# How to validate an IANA string with nodatime?

Tags: c#, nodatime

```
var easternTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneIdentifier];
```

Using NodaTime how should I validate that when the string timeZoneIdentifier is set to a valid IANA string like "Europe/Stockholm" it is deemed valid but an unsupported IANA string is rejected.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: What's the difference between an *unsupported* string and an invalid string? Just catch the `TimeZoneNotFound` exception, or try for the null reference from `GetZoneOrNull` and consider that good enough?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will accept Matt Johnson's answer as it has a code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(timeZoneIdentifier);
bool valid = tz != null;
```

Or, as an extension method:

```
public static bool IsValidTimeZone(this IDateTimeZoneProvider provider, string timeZoneId)
{
    return provider.GetZoneOrNull(timeZoneId) != null;
}
```